# Access Item in Array for text in TextView

Tags: objective-c, arrays, object, parse-platform, textview

I have a `PFQuery` that is querying a certain set of objects that I need to be displayed in a `TextView`. Normally I would do this like so:

```
NSMutableString *favTeamsText = [NSMutableString string];
for (NSString *team in currentUser[@"FavTeams"]) {
    [favTeamsText appendFormat:@"%@\n", team];
}
```

This will fill my `TextView` with the following:

```
Team 1
Team 2
...
```

The problem is I need to specify this array. So I am running something like so:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"AllTeams"];
    [query whereKey:@"league" equalTo:firstTeamFavButton.titleLabel.text];
    [query whereKey:@"title" containedIn:favTeamsForCurrentUser];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {

} else {
...

}];
```

What I need to do now is get these `objects` into my tableview. If I were to try to do this like the following:

```
    NSMutableString *favTeamsForLeague1 = [NSMutableString string];
    for (NSString *team in objects) {
        [favTeamsForLeague1 appendFormat:@"%@\n", team];
    }
    favTeamsTextView.text = favTeamsForLeague1;
```

My `TextView` prints something like the following:

```
<AllTeams: ...., objectId:...> { league = NHL; title = "NHL Team1"; }
<AllTeams: ...., objectId:...> { league = NHL; title = "NHL Team2"; }
```

What I would like to do is print out something more like :

```
NHL Team 1
NHL Team 2
```

I know I need to sort this out somehow maybe like `objectForKey:`? I could do what I am try to achieve by running `PFObject *object = [objects objectAtIndex:0];` about 100 times but of course that is not particle.

What is the best way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: You're appending the team object, what you want to do is append the team title. `[favTeamsForLeague1 appendFormat:@"%@\n", team.title];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like in your "objects" array you don't have just the team name but a dictionary with keys "league" and "team".
Change your code like this:

```
for (NSDictionary* team in objects)
{
    [favTeamsForLeague1 appendFormat:@"%@\n", team[@"title"]];
}
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much! I really appreciate it!